# Replace values in a row of a dataframe after specific value criteria

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am trying to solve a little problem with a data frame in R. I have a dataframe with this style (I add `dput()` version in the final part):

```
  ID x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1 ab  F  F  G  G  G
2 an  A  B  F  G  G
3 am  B  B  B  C  B
4 ap  F  F  F  F  F
5 aq  A  B  C  F  G
```

I am trying to build a function to apply in every row. This function identify any `F` in a row and the values after the position of `F` will be filled with `F`. I would like to get something like this:

```
  ID x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1 ab  F  F  F  F  F
2 an  A  B  F  F  F
3 am  B  B  B  C  B
4 ap  F  F  F  F  F
5 aq  A  B  C  F  F
```

For example in the first row you can see this row has 3 `F` and after final `F` all elements were filled with `G`. The same happens with other rows with any `F`. For me is so complex working with index and I have tried with `if` solution like this:

```
Base[-1] <- t(apply(
  Base[-1],
  1,
  function(x) {
    if("F" %in% x) {
      x[which.max(x=="F"):length(x)]="F" 
      } else
      x
  }
))
```

And I got this result that is not correct:

```
  ID x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1 ab  F  F  B  F  F
2 an  F  F  B  F  F
3 am  F  F  B  F  F
4 ap  F  F  C  F  F
5 aq  F  F  B  F  F
```

The `dput()` version of my dataframe `Base` is the next:

```
structure(list(ID = c("ab", "an", "am", "ap", "aq"), x1 = c("F", 
"A", "B", "F", "A"), x2 = c("F", "B", "B", "F", "B"), x3 = c("G", 
"F", "B", "F", "C"), x4 = c("G", "G", "C", "F", "F"), x5 = c("G", 
"G", "B", "F", "G")), .Names = c("ID", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", 
"x5"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close
which.max(x=='F') was looking at a vector of 0s and 1s rather than index numbers

```
Base <- structure(list(ID = c("ab", "an", "am", "ap", "aq"), x1 = c("F", 
  "A", "B", "F", "A"), x2 = c("F", "B", "B", "F", "B"), x3 = c("G", 
  "F", "B", "F", "C"), x4 = c("G", "G", "C", "F", "F"), x5 = c("G", 
  "G", "B", "F", "G")), .Names = c("ID", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", 
  "x5"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

Base[-1] <- t(apply(
    Base[-1],
    1,
    function(x) {
      if("F" %in% x) {
        x[max(which(x=="F")):length(x)]="F" 
        }
      x }
    ))
```

should work

```
Base
  ID x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1 ab  F  F  F  F  F
2 an  A  B  F  F  F
3 am  B  B  B  C  B
4 ap  F  F  F  F  F
5 aq  A  B  C  F  F
```